# How to customise Android's Navigation Bar (bottom soft keys)

Tags: android, softkeys

There is a lot of questions/answers about *application's* navigation bar but I can't find anything specific to the bottom bar (maybe my wording isn't right?). I'm aware I need root for this (no issue here), I just can't find any information where to look, where is this handled in AOSP.

I need it for a custom device where some of the buttons are not mandatory/used.